# can survivor space full triggers a full gc?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In my tomcat application , I am seeing very frequent full GCs even though the oldgen is not full (atleast 20% free) . I have observed the PS Survivor space 100% utilized most of the time . Can this trigger a full GC ? or can it trigger minor GC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this trigger a full GC ?

If the survivour space fills up during a minor GC it triggers a full collection.

> or can it trigger minor GC ?

It will only have objects added to it during a minor collection, so the only way is to attempt a full collection.

Most likely you survivor ration is too low.

> oldgen is not full (atleast 20% free)

I would suggest your heap should be 50% - 70% free after a full collection to give your application plenty of head room. I tend to have 90+% free after a full GC.